# How to Load A UIViewController From A .XIB?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, xib

HI I have a app where I want to load a UIViewController from a .xib file, called ImageViewController.

[image]

I have created the .h and .m files for ImageViewController. I have declared a IBOutlet to it in the Application delegate.

I have on many occasions dragged and dropped a UIView (for example) and it is usually initialised by the nib. As there is a UIViewController object in IB I assume you must be able to do the same. If so what method is called in the UIViewController? For example I know awakeFromNib is called in a view.

Cheers In advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is to use awakeFromNib. It appears that it is part of the NSObject UIKit Additions References, not a UIView method. There for you should be able to use it for all classes you are instantiating from the nib.

Easy when you know how.